# Problem with jquery live method

Tags: event-handling, jquery

I have something like wall posts which have the option of 'remove'. Since posts can be added any time hence I'm using jquery live method for event handling.
The problem is, multiple events are getting attached to 'remove' on click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.actions .remove_wall_post').live('click', function(){
                var wall_post_id = $(this).attr('id');
                var data = {
                  'action' : 'remove',
                  'wall_post_id' : wall_post_id
                };
                var url = myurl;
                $.post(url, data, function(response){
                    if(response == '1'){
                        $('#post_list #'+wall_post_id).hide();
                        var total_posts = $('#total_posts').text();
                    } else{
                        alert('ERROR');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
});
```

Suppose there are n posts, when I click on 'remove' of any post, the first event works fine...but after that i get n ERROR alerts and all events have the same wall_post_id

Comment: probably need to see the html this jQuery is effecting to understand what's going on

Comment: Finally found a fix...the problem was the pop up(in which event was defined),the live event was getting attached everytime I closed and opened the pop up...so basically the event was getting attached as many times as the state of pop up was changing. FIX :: before calling live method...make sure no other event is attached by using die() method.